# Datasheet LTC3892 - how to calculate Rc, Cc1 and Cc2?

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I am working on building a DC/DC converter using the LTC3892 chip. I went through the calculations in their datasheet for the chip, but they don't specify any formulas for Rc, Cc1 and Cc2. I don't see any correlation between the values they used in their application circuits either. The only mention of these components are on page 27.

Does anyone know how to calculate these values, or at least how they got their values for the example circuits they provided (pg 31,32, 33, 36)?

[image: Example from page 33]

Link to the datasheet: http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/38921f.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The section "Checking Transient Response" basically suggests building it with the shown values as a starting point and playing with it to optimize the transient response. Presumably the LTSpice model is good enough to get started if you have unusual conditions.